# Return boolean value from oracle function

Tags: oracle, function, boolean

Trying to return value from function

```
create or replace function compairenumber(num1 in number,num2 in number)
return boolean is
begin
if num1 < num2 then
return true;
else 
return false;
end if;
end;
```

when i'm giving query 
select compairenumber(5,10) from dual
its not returning true or false.

Answer (score 11):

Boolean values can only be used in other PL/SQL code, **not** in Oracle SQL. If you want a function whose return value is available in a `select ... from dual` then you will need to define the function to return `varchar2` with the return values `'true'` and `'false'` respectively (or `'T'` and `'F'`, or return number, with the values 1 and 0).

As sad as this is, Oracle SQL does not support the Boolean data type (although the programming language PL/SQL does).

Comment: so it means i should write something like this
create or replace function compairenumber(num1 in number,num2 in number)
return varchar is
begin
if num1 < num2 then
return 'T';
else 
return 'F';
end if;
end;

Comment: @ashish - exactly. Except that in Oracle it is better (for now) to use the `varchar2` data type, rather than `varchar`.

Comment: I prefer this answer as it explains WHY you can't use BOOLEAN in that situation.

Comment: Now this has changed in 23c version of Oracle. It now supports Boolean datatype and `to_boolean` function can convert varchar, int to boolean datatype. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/to_boolean.html#GUID-B4FA8F5F-DD2A-4BEA-946A-B3CA60509294

Answer (score 5):

use return varchar2

```
create or replace function compairenumber(num1 in number, num2 in number)
  return varchar2 is
begin
  if num1 < num2 then
    return 'TRUE';
  else
    return 'FALSE';
  end if;
end;


select CASE
         WHEN compairenumber(5, 10) = 'TRUE' THEN
          'OK'
         ELSE
          'NOT'
       END
  from dual
```